# Запускается grub вместо виндовс

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил Ubuntu, но после перезагрузки запускается grub. Как запустить Виндовс?

Comment: Запустить BIOS, и выбрать в меню нужный пункт для автозагрузки.

Answer (score 1):

Во время установки любого линуха, как правило, устанавливается grub. При этом, в IPL загрузочного HDD помещается указание на область на диске, в которой размещён grub.

По идее, grub должен посмотреть таблицу загрузочных дисков (показать меню, если таких несколько) и передать управление уже **конкретному** загрузчику той или иной ОС. В Вашем случае groob не может этого сделать. Почему - ответ не очевидный.

Наиболее вероятная причина - установка Ubuntu шла с какими-то ошибками. Возможно Вы перецепляли диски после установки, возможнот - изменяли их порядок в BIOS...  Совет - зайдите в BIOS и посмотрите внимательно раздел "Порядок загрузки"

Возможно, во время установки Ubuntu Вы как-то неправильно распределили дисковые разделы или вообще пропустили это шаг. Тогда, скорее всего, винда накрылась медным тазом... Совет - загрузитесь с Live CD или флешки, запустите *fdisk* и посмотрите сначала список дисков (fdisk -l) а потом - список разделов на том диске, который должен содержать ОС.

Возможно, у вас конфликт с UEFI. Я в этом плохо разбираюсь и просто сразу отключаю эту мерзость до установки ОС.

Comment: "grub должен посмотреть" ничего он не смотрит и не должен. что есть в grub.cfg то и покажет.